# Flutter - Null check operator used on a null value _CastError

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement, that when the User has no Internet Connection(Not Connected to Wlan, Ethernet or Cellular) to display a separate Page. For that I use the connectivity_plus Plugin in Version 2.0.1, Flutter 2.5.2 and **NO** Null-Sound-Safety.

Switching the Smartphone to Airplane mode from Wlan or Cellular Connection the InternetConnection Page is displayed but disabling Airplanemode and having Cellular or Wlan I get ***The following _CastError was thrown building Builder(dirty): Null check operator used on a null value***.

I tried to use Conditional Operators that didn't helped added the home function to the else Statement and added also there the Conditional Operator for the home and for the initialRoute that also didn't helped and now I'm clueless and what I can do.

**Error**

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following _CastError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
flutter: Null check operator used on a null value
flutter:
flutter: The relevant error-causing widget was:
flutter:   MaterialApp MaterialApp:file:///Users/blackbox/Desktop/name/example/lib/main.dart:170:18
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      _WidgetsAppState._onGenerateRoute.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart:1353:48)
flutter: #1      MaterialPageRoute.buildContent (package:flutter/src/material/page.dart:53:55)
flutter: #2      MaterialRouteTransitionMixin.buildPage (package:flutter/src/material/page.dart:106:27)
flutter: #3      _ModalScopeState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:851:55)
flutter: #4      Builder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:8004:48)
flutter: #5      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4739:28)
flutter: #6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4665:15)
flutter: #7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #8      StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:5)
flutter: #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
flutter: #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #12     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
flutter: #13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #14     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #15     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
flutter: #16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #17     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
flutter: #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #19     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5700:32)
flutter: #20     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6356:17)
flutter: #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #22     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #23     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
flutter: #24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #25     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
flutter: #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #27     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
flutter: #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #29     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #30     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
flutter: #31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #32     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
flutter: #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #34     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
flutter: #35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #36     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #37     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
flutter: #38     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #39     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
flutter: #40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #41     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
flutter: #42     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #43     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #44     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
flutter: #45     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #46     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
flutter: #47     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #48     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #49     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #50     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:5)
flutter: #51     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #52     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #53     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
flutter: #54     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #55     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
flutter: #56     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #57     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
flutter: #58     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #59     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
flutter: #60     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #61     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #62     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #63     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5020:5)
flutter: #64     _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:181:11)
flutter: #65     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #66     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
flutter: #67     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #68     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #69     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
flutter: #70     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #71     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
flutter: #72     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #73     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #74     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #75     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5020:5)
flutter: #76     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #77     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #78     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #79     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5020:5)
flutter: #80     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #81     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #82     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
flutter: #83     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #84     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
flutter: #85     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #86     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #87     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #88     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:5)
flutter: #89     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #90     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #91     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #92     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:5)
flutter: #93     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #94     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
flutter: #95     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #96     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #97     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #98     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5020:5)
flutter: #99     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #100    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #101    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #102    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5020:5)
flutter: #103    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #104    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #105    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
flutter: #106    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #107    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
flutter: #108    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #109    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #110    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
flutter: #111    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #112    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
flutter: #113    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #114    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
flutter: #115    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
flutter: #116    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
flutter: #117    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2620:33)
flutter: #118    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
flutter: #119    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:319:5)
flutter: #120    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1143:15)
flutter: #121    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1080:9)
flutter: #122    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:996:5)
flutter: #126    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:166:10)
flutter: #127    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:270:5)
flutter: #128    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:129:31)
flutter: (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
```

**Main.dart File**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:app/env.dart';
import 'package:app/generated/l10n.dart';
import 'package:app/provider/app_clock.dart';
import 'package:app/provider/auth.dart';
import 'package:app/provider/internet_connection.dart';
import 'package:app/provider/local_auth.dart';
import 'package:app/provider/therapist.dart';
import 'package:app/provider/therapy.dart';
import 'package:app/provider/user.dart';
import 'package:app/routes.dart';
import 'package:app/services.dart';
import 'package:app/theme.dart';
import 'package:app/ui/screens/setup/internet_connection.dart';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase_android/in_app_purchase_android.dart';
import 'package:localizely_sdk/localizely_sdk.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'util/http_overrides.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    // For the GooglePlay billing library 2.0 on Android, it is mandatory to call
    // [enablePendingPurchases](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.Builder.html#enablependingpurchases)
    // as part of initializing the app.
    InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition.enablePendingPurchases();
  }

  if (AppEnv.LOCALIZELY_SDK_TOKEN.isNotEmpty) {
    Localizely.init(
      AppEnv.LOCALIZELY_SDK_TOKEN,
      AppEnv.LOCALIZELY_DISTRUBUTION_ID,
    ); // Init sdk

    Localizely.setPreRelease(true);
    await S.load(S.delegate.supportedLocales.first);

    try {
      dynamic result = await Localizely.updateTranslations();
      AppEnv.localizelySDKenabled = true;
      AppEnv.currentLocalizelyReleaseId = result.newReleaseId;
    } catch (e) {
      AppEnv.localizelySDKenabled = false;
    }
  } else {
    await S.load(S.delegate.supportedLocales.first);
  }

  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);

  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();

  bool isFirebaseInit = false;
  String errorMessage = '';
  try {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    // All Services and Providers are being initialized
    setupServices(); //needs Firebase
    // And we are waiting until that's done
    print("Wating for services");

    await services.allReady(timeout: Duration(seconds: 60));

    print("Services initialized");

    // Force disable Crashlytics collection while doing every day development.
    // Temporarily toggle this to true if you want to test crash reporting in your app.
    if (kDebugMode) {
      // Crashlytics does not support web for now. See two other kIsWeb too.
      if (!kIsWeb) {
        await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance
            .setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
      }
    }

    if (!kIsWeb) {
      // Pass all uncaught errors from the framework to Crashlytics.
      FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
    }
    isFirebaseInit = true;
  } on Exception catch (exception, stack) {
    errorMessage += "'${exception.toString()}'\n\nStack:\n${stack.toString()}";
  } catch (error, stack) {
    errorMessage += "'${error.toString()}'\n\nStack:\n${stack.toString()}";
  }

  if (!isFirebaseInit) {
    runApp(
      Container(
        color: const Color(0xff008587),
        child: Center(
          child: Text('''Es tut uns Leid!

Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Wenden Sie sich bitte an .
          
$errorMessage''', textScaleFactor: 0.8, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } else {
    runZonedGuarded(() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      runApp(
        MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: services.get<ConnectivityService>(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: services.get<AppClock>(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: services.get<UserProvider>(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: services.get<TherapyProvider>(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: services.get<AuthProvider>(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: services.get<TherapistProvider>(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: services.get<LocalAuthProvider>(),
            ),
          ],
          child: MyApp(),
        ),
      );
    }, (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      if (!kIsWeb) {
        FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stackTrace);
      }
    });
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer3<UserProvider, AppClock, ConnectivityService>(
      builder: (context, userProvider, clock, connectivityService, _) {
        if (connectivityService.connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
          return MaterialApp(
            localizationsDelegates: [
              S.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
            ],
            supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
            home: InternetConnection(),
          );
        } else {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: '',
            theme: AppTheme.base,
            routes: Routes.routes,
            initialRoute: services.get<UserProvider>().guessInitialRoute(),
            localizationsDelegates: [
              S.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
            ],
            supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot or code of you ```main.dart``` file?

Comment: @SahebSingh This is the Main.dart File